# Передать в Controller объект из Main

Tags: java, javafx

Как передать контроллеру объект, который создается в методе `main()`?

Пример:

```java
public class MainApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Some some = new Some(); // это нужно передать в контроллер, но необходимо создавать в Main

            launch(args); // как я понимаю здесь создается объект контроллера
    }
}

class Controller implements Initializable {
      
       Some some; // используется здесь
       @FXML
       Button btn;

       public void clkBtn(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            some.somethingDoing("хочу что-то передать");
      }
}
```

Comment: А почему нельзя объявить `some` как `public static Some some;` в классе `MainApp`, в `main()` написать `... some = new Some (Some1) ...` и в классе `Controller`   использовать как `MainApp.some.somethingDoing("что-то хочу передать"); `? Объект ведь все равно создаётся в `main()`

Comment: о, спасибо за идею! сейчас опробую)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
launch(args); // как я понимаю здесь создается объект контроллера
```

нет, объект контроллера создается только при его загрузке.
Чтобы загрузить контроллер, можно  воспользоваться кодом

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("тут путь до fxml файла"));
Parent mainView = loader.load(); //тут происходит загрузка вью и инициализация контроллера ( через метод initialize)
Controller controller = loader.getController();

Some some = new Some();
controller.setSome(some); //проставляете значение в котроллер
```

Comment: спасибо! помогло!